# Incomplete and strange words from serial Arduino to Android

Tags: android, arduino

I use the tutorial *[Data transfer between Android and Arduino via Bluetooth](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php)* to receive code from Arduino.

I made a textview with the id txtArduino, and I use `.append`, but why do I get incomplete text when the Arduino sends?

For example:

> LED ON, and:w- . iin:13

And similar strange text like this.

How can I fix this problem?

PS: I can provide more code if needed.

#### Android Header

```
h = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                     // If receive massage
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);   // Create string from bytes array
                sb.append(strIncom);                                  // Append string
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");              // Determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                             // If end-of-line,
                    String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex); // Extract string
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());                        // And clear
                    txtArduino.append(sbprint + "\n");                // Update TextView

                    //toggleDOOR.setEnabled(true);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "...Mesaj:"+ sb.toString() +  " Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                break;
            }
    };
};
```

#### Arduino Code:

```
int cnt = 0;
int pinLed = 13;

String myKey = "0000001";

//Pin Geam Masina 2 si 3
int pinGeamInchis = 2;
int pinGeamDeschis = 3;

char incomingByte;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //INITIALIZARE
    pinMode(pinLed,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pinGeamInchis,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pinGeamDeschis,OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(pinLed,LOW);

    Serial.print("Modul ON( KEY:");
    Serial.print(myKey);
    Serial.print(" )\r\n");
}

void loop(){
    if(Serial.available()> 0){
        incomingByte = Serial.read();
        if(incomingByte == '0'){
            //Opreste LED
            digitalWrite(pinLed,LOW);
            Serial.print("Pin 13: LED OFF\r\n");

            //Inchide Geam
            digitalWrite(pinGeamInchis,HIGH);
            Serial.print("Command:W-C\r\n");
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(pinGeamInchis,LOW);
            Serial.print("Pin 2:Window Down\r\n");
        }
        if(incomingByte == '1'){
            //Aprinde LED
            digitalWrite(pinLed,HIGH);
            Serial.print("LED ON\r\n");

            //Deschide Geam
            digitalWrite(pinGeamDeschis,HIGH);
            Serial.print("Command:W-O\r\n");
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(pinGeamDeschis,LOW);
            Serial.print("Pin 3:Window Up\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I see, if I send only one "command", it works. What can I do so I can receive more commands at ones on serial and on Android?

PS: I use [Arduino Nano](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano).

Comment: 1. Are you sure you are using the correct baud-rate for the BT module? Is it set to comunicate at 9600bps? 2. How is your Arduino clocked? Quartz? At which frequency?

Comment: the module is set to 9600bps

Comment: the idea is that If I use a bluetooth terminal from google play it works with no errors or stuff , I get exactly what I send on serial.

Answer (score 0):

## Analysis

Looking at your Android code:

```
String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex); // Extract string
sb.delete(0, sb.length());                        // And clear
txtArduino.append(sbprint + "\n");                // Update TextView
```

You take the message that was received up to the (first) newline and then delete the whole message. I think, one cannot be sure how much data will be inside any given "message" received.

For instance, when the Arduino does:

```
Serial.print("Pin 13: LED OFF\r\n");
// [...]
Serial.print("Command:W-C\r\n");
```

this will be sent to the BT module just the same as:

```
Serial.print("Pin 13: LED OFF\r\nCommand:W-C\r\n");
```

And then "someone" (BT module? Android OS? ...?) may decide to put this in *two* "messages" (or "packets"), for example

```
Message1: "Pin 13: LED OFF\r\nComm"
Message2: "and:W-C\r\n"
```

In this case, you would then only see

```
"Pin 13: LED OFF"
```

and

```
"and:W-C"
```

displayed, because you deleted the `"Comm"` part of the first message.

## Suggestion

Try and replace your `sb.delete(0, sb.length());` with `sb.delete(0, endOfLineIndex + "\r\n".length());`, so that you don't delete the whole string but only the part that is actually displayed and keep the rest to be completed by the next message.

You should then also add a loop to make sure your code will not fail when more than one newline is in a message. For this, simply replace:

```
int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n"); // Determine the end-of-line
if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                // If end-of-line,
```

with

```
int endOfLineIndex; 
while ( (endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n")) > 0) { // While there's at least one complete line in buffer,
```

Comment: I did what you suggested I still get strange strings , if I send 199 sometimes I get 999

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending print("/r/n") on the Arduino side just put a empty System.println();

Like this:

```
void taskTransmitData(void)
{
  // start the xml
  Serial.print("HE");
  Serial.print(pMyMemory->currentHeading);
  Serial.print("/HE");

---- 

  Serial.print("CS");
  Serial.print(currentState);
  Serial.print("/CS");

  Serial.println();

}
```

On the android side, this should work:

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) buffer;
String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, bytes); // create string from bytes array
sb.append(strIncom);      // append string
int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");  // determine the end-of-line
if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {  
    // add the current string to eol to a local string
    String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);

    // get the start and end indexes of the heading
    int startHeading = sb.indexOf("HE");
    int endHeading = sb.indexOf("/HE");

    // set the heading
    Henry.this.setCurrentHeading(sb.substring((startHeading + 2), endHeading));

    ......

    // get the start and end indexes of the current state
    int startCS = sb.indexOf("CS");
    int endCS = sb.indexOf("/CS");

    // set the current state
    Henry.this.currentState = sb.substring((startCS + 2), endCS);

    // output what we have
    //System.out.println("recv: " + sbprint);
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());   
}
```